# Error when decoding QR Code

Tags: java, qr-code, zxing

I'm decoding an Qr Code that i'm getting throw the Java JSANE API. when i'm writing the image i got from the JSANE API in a file before reading it with IMAGEIO.read(), the decodong process is working but when i'm using the ilage Object given from the JSANE API directly without writing it in a file before reading, i' getting the following error :

`Exception in thread "main" com.google.zxing.NotFoundException`

The method i'm using are:

```
public String decode_QrCode(String filePath, String charset) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, NotFoundException{
    System.out.println("ICI ERREUR");
        BinaryBitmap binaryBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(
                new HybridBinarizer(
                        new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(
                                ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream(filePath))
                        )
                )
        );

        Result qrCodeResult = new MultiFormatReader().decode(binaryBitmap);

        return qrCodeResult.getText();

}

public String decode_QrCode_buffImg(BufferedImage bufferedImage) throws NotFoundException{

    LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(bufferedImage);
    BinaryBitmap binaryBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(
            new HybridBinarizer(
                    source
            )
    );

    Result qrCodeResult = new MultiFormatReader().decode(binaryBitmap);

    return qrCodeResult.getText();

}
```

I'm getting the image from the JSANE API like this:

```
Image image = dialog.openDialog();
```

I'm converting the Image to BufferedImage like this:

```
public static BufferedImage toBufferedImage(Image image)
{
     if (image instanceof BufferedImage)
            return (BufferedImage)image;

            // This code ensures that all the pixels in the image are loaded
            image = new ImageIcon(image).getImage();

            // Determine if the image has transparent pixels
            boolean hasAlpha = hasAlpha(image);

            // Create a buffered image with a format that's compatible with the screen
            BufferedImage bimage = null;

            GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();

            try {
                // Determine the type of transparency of the new buffered image
                int transparency = Transparency.OPAQUE;

                if (hasAlpha == true)
                    transparency = Transparency.BITMASK;

                // Create the buffered image
                GraphicsDevice gs = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
                GraphicsConfiguration gc = gs.getDefaultConfiguration();

                bimage = gc.createCompatibleImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), transparency);
            } catch (HeadlessException e) { } //No screen

            if (bimage == null) {
                // Create a buffered image using the default color model
                int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB;

                if (hasAlpha == true) {type = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;}
                    bimage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), type);
            }

            // Copy image to buffered image
            Graphics g = bimage.createGraphics();

            // Paint the image onto the buffered image
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
            g.dispose();

            return bimage;
}
```

This the main function of the class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, cf, NotFoundException {
    Frame frame = null;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    JSaneDialog dialog = new JSaneDialog( JSaneDialog.CP_START_SANED_LOCALHOST, 
            frame, "JSaneDialog", true, null);

    Image image = dialog.openDialog();


    BufferedImage buffImg = toBufferedImage(image);

    //BufferedImage buff = resize(buffImg, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, buffImg.getWidth()/2, buffImg.getHeight()/2, 0.5, 0.5);

    ImageIO.write(buffImg, "png", new File("/home/michaelyamsi/Bureau/Mémoires/test/test.png"));


    QrCode New_Qr = new QrCode();
    System.out.println("QR Code decompressed : " +  New_Qr.decode_QrCode("/home/michaelyamsi/Bureau/Mémoires/test/test.png", "UTF-8"));
    System.out.println("QR Code decompressed : " +  New_Qr.decode_QrCode_buffImg(buffImg));
```

}

I'have even tried to resize th BufferedImage before using it but when i'm doing that, even the decode from the resultant file is not working.

Comment: the error you get is not enough, what is the error stacktrace?

Comment: the problem is taht is the only error line that i get when executing my code.

Comment: This is the main function:

Comment: Have you tried putting your test.png image in a directory whose path does not contain the 'é' character? Paths containing spaces or non ascii characters are a huge source of errors.

Comment: Thanks, StephaneM for your answer, but reading from the "test.png" image doesn't cause any problem, but it's decoding from the BufferedImage directly without writing it in the test.png file that cause problem.