# zxing qrcode, error on read. com.google.zxing.NotFoundException

Tags: java, zxing

Am trying to read the qrcode from a image file uploaded from a jsp file. To read QRcode i have used zxing jars.

code from

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
import com.google.zxing.BinaryBitmap;
import com.google.zxing.EncodeHintType;
import com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader;
import com.google.zxing.NotFoundException;
import com.google.zxing.Result;
import com.google.zxing.WriterException;
import com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource;
import com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix;
import com.google.zxing.common.HybridBinarizer;
import com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeWriter;
import com.google.zxing.qrcode.decoder.ErrorCorrectionLevel;

public class GenerateQRCode {
public String readQRCode(String filePath, String charset)
          throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, NotFoundException {

        Hashtable hintMap = new Hashtable();
    hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.L);

    BinaryBitmap binaryBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(
        new BufferedImageLuminanceSource( ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream(filePath)))));

    **Result qrCodeResult = new MultiFormatReader().decode(binaryBitmap, hintMap);**
    return qrCodeResult.getText();
  }
```

}

This is the method where am trying to get the qrcode value in the string "result".

```
String result = rr.readQRCode(tmpFile.getCanonicalPath(), "UTF-8");
```

the following error is thrown in the above called method at the bold line.
com.google.zxing.NotFoundException

already i find the repetition of the same question in stackoverflow.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27770665/error-when-decoding-qr-code
```

but no proper  response for it. Will this code work. or should i look for alternative.  I have completed the code for generating a qrcode. reading the code from a file is the issue with zxing.

Comment: can you post the actual exception text (stack trace)?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I found this https://github.com/zxing/zxing/issues/216

You should put PURE_BARCODE hints. So, your code should be

```
// ...

Map<DecodeHintType, Object> hints = new EnumMap<>(DecodeHintType.class);
hints.put(DecodeHintType.PURE_BARCODE, true);

Result qrCodeResult = new MultiFormatReader().decode(binaryBitmap, hints);
return qrCodeResult.getText();

// ...
```